# Saving Django formset with Many to Many Field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm building a little app with a formset that lets me enter a number of game scores each linking to a player via a many to many field. I'm having problems getting this to save properly with various errors. Basic code.

Model.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

class Score(models.Model):
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    turn = models.ForeignKey(Turn)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)  

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.score
```

Each score is then joined to a turn but I haven't shown that bit.

Form.py

```
class NewScore(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Score
        fields = ('score', 'players',)
```

View.py

```
def newscore(request):

NewScoreFormSet = formset_factory(NewScore, extra=2)  

if request.method == 'POST':

    formset = NewScoreFormSet(request.POST)

    if formset.is_valid():

        t = Turn.objects.latest('id')

        for form in formset:

            p = form.cleaned_data.get('players')

            scoreSave = form.save(commit=False)
            scoreSave.turn = t
            scoreSave.save()
            scoreSave.players.add(p)


    else:
        print 'Formset not OK'

    return render(request, 'scorer/game.html',
                {})

else:

    formset = NewScoreFormSet()

    return render(request, 'scorer/game.html',
                {'formset': formset,})
```

The issue seems to be around getting the player saved through the many to many field and in this current setup I get the error message

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'

I have also tried removing the line

```
scoreSave.players.add(p)
```

but that just doesn't save the player at all. Just the score and turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add()` method used for associating instances in many-to-many relations takes one or more *individual* model instances. You cannot pass an entire list/queryset of players, but you can add them one by one:

```
for player in p:
    scoreSave.players.add(player)
```

Of course this is rather verbose, so you can use python's syntax sugar for calling `add()` with all instances at once:

```
scoreSave.players.add(*p) # same as scoreSave.players.add(p[0], p[1], ...)
```